# can incremental view maintenance be used on postgresql13?

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I'm currently using this timescaleDB integrated with postgresql13, I found this patch called incremental view maintenance which i think is also very important for my project

https://github.com/sraoss/pgsql-ivm

can pgsql-ivm be possibly be installed in postgresql13? So that I can use both of them at them same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably a PostgreSQL version with [this patch](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/34/2138/) applied.

This has been [under discussion](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/20181227215726.4d166b4874f8983a641123f5@sraoss.co.jp) for a while, but didn't make it into the source tree so far.

I wouldn't dare use that yet, unless I have good reason to trust the code and am ready to take care of that patch and apply it to PostgreSQL for each new update.

My advice is to roll your own using a regular table and triggers.

Comment: I found this one. It seems much more mature? https://github.com/MaterializeInc/materialize

Comment: No idea (I didn't read the code). My advice stands. Asking for recommendations for tools is off-topic...